# attempt to push_back a lvalue with move ctor deleted, doesn't compile

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct Foo 
{  
    Foo( ) = default;
    Foo(Foo&& f) = delete;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
};

int main()
{  
    std::vector<Foo> v;
    Foo f;
    v.push_back(f);
    std::cin.ignore(); 
}

// error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(Foo &&)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Is this behavior is standard ( I am under msvc2013 november CTP) ?

I thought here, only the copy constructor will be invoked.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. [GCC accepts it](http://ideone.com/t7C7O4), for what it's worth.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug. This code compiles cleanly with clang 3.4 trunk.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: This is not a bug. As per private communications with Stephan Lavavej, 23.2.1/13 from N3797 states: 

— T is CopyInsertable into X means that, in addition to T being MoveInsertable into X [...]

"in addition to" seems to imply CI requires MI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree this looks like a bug.  That being said, you almost certainly do not want to code your `Foo` this way.

What you are saying above is:

> I don't ever want to move **or copy** a `Foo` from an rvalue.

You can not return such a `Foo` from a factory function.  And while you can `push_back` it into a `vector<Foo>`, you can't `insert` it into one.  This is an extremely fragile type with surprising behavior.

As it stands, it might not be too surprising you can't insert into a `vector`, because `Foo` has no accessible assignment operator at all:  the copy assignment operator is deleted, and the move assignment operator doesn't exist at all.  Let's continue the design philosophy above and give `Foo` assignment operators:

```
struct Foo 
{  
    Foo( ) = default;
    Foo(Foo&& f) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&& f) = delete;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
};
```

Now can you insert this into a `vector<Foo>`?

No, you still can not.  Not even at the end:

```
v.insert(v.end(), f);

In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from ../libcxx/include/iostream:38:
In file included from ../libcxx/include/ios:216:
In file included from ../libcxx/include/__locale:15:
In file included from ../libcxx/include/string:439:
In file included from ../libcxx/include/algorithm:627:
../libcxx/include/memory:1641:31: error: call to deleted constructor of 'Foo'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../libcxx/include/memory:1568:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator<Foo>::construct<Foo, Foo>' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
../libcxx/include/memory:1449:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<Foo> >::__construct<Foo, Foo>' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, pointer, _Args...>(),
             ^
../libcxx/include/vector:1651:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<Foo> >::construct<Foo, Foo>' requested here
        __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(),
                        ^
../libcxx/include/vector:1677:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<Foo, std::__1::allocator<Foo> >::__move_range' requested here
            __move_range(__p, this->__end_, __p + 1);
            ^
test.cpp:25:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<Foo, std::__1::allocator<Foo> >::insert' requested here
    v.insert(v.end(), f);
      ^
test.cpp:9:5: note: 'Foo' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    Foo(Foo&& f) = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

During `insert`, along one branch of the logic, the `vector` will try to move elements down the existing buffer to try to create a "hole" in the middle.  Even though this branch won't be executed if you are inserting at the end, that fact isn't discovered until run time.

If you don't want your type to have move semantics, the way to do that is to explicitly give it copy semantics (using = default is fine), and to **not** give it move semantics, deleted or otherwise:

```
struct Foo 
{  
    Foo( ) = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
};
```

Now you can insert this into `vector<Foo>`.  You can return it from factory functions.  It doesn't have move members, not even implicitly.  If you copy this from an rvalue, the copy members are used instead of the (non-existent) move members.

And for bonus points, this works around the MSVC++ bug.

There is a **huge** difference between deleted move members, and *non-existent* move members.

Deleted move members attract rvalue arguments, and if they bind, result in a compile-time error.  Non-existent move members do not attract any arguments at all.  Therefore other overloads, such as copy members, are available to be chosen by overload resolution.  rvalues in particular will get (often confusingly) snagged by deleted move members.  But with nonexistent move members, rvalues are free to bind to (traditional `const&`) copy members.

In summary:

> Never<sup>1</sup> specify deleted move members.

1) "Never" is an exaggeration.  But if you ever find yourself coding deleted move members, or reviewing them in someone else's code, you should be asking yourself:  Why are these here?!  Is this programmer *intimately* familiar with *every* aspect of move semantics?!  Can the programmer explain why deleted move semantics are present beyond: "I don't want to use move semantics?"  If not, remove the deleted move semantics.

Comment: when you specified `Foo(const Foo&) = default;` and therefore as you said supress move capacity for a arbitrary type, is there a difference between `delete` the move constructor versus not mention it at all inside the class definition ?

Comment: @Guillaume07:  Very much so.  Indeed that is the point of my post.  I will update it to emphasize that fact.

Comment: yeah sorry I just understand that your post precisely tell that

Comment: No worries, I think you improved my post.

Comment: when you say: "the copy assignment operator is deleted", it's surprise me because I don"t mention it at all inside the class definition. Is it because I have defaulted the copy constructor ?

Comment: @Guillaume07:  Nope.  If you *declare* either move member (user-defined, =default, or =delete), then copy members not explicitly declared are implicitly deleted.

Comment: another bug in msvc2013 nomvember ctp we can't default the move constructor